# How can i pull selected files from git repo

Tags: git, version-control

I have the git repo with folders like

```
|-ear
   |-ejbs
   |---src
   |-----main
   |-------resources
   |---------META-INF
   |-primary-source
   |-projects
   |---logging
   |-servlets
   |---servlet
   |-----src
   |-------main
   |---------webapp
   |-----------WEB-INF
   |-src
   |---main
   |-----resources
```

This is in git repo on bitbucket

However for other project i only want to have folder structure like

```
|-ear
   |-main
   |-resources
   |-projects --only some files
```

So that when i use git pull then those files folder gets updated from that repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

If you only need a subset:

- clone the original repo
- drop files you don't need
- commit what's remaining.

Or, if you're not interested in the history, just create a fresh repo and pick the files you need from `ear` into your fresh repo.

Comment: i can do that and create fresh repo but how will keep the files in syn with original repo which are now in repo 2